# Aggregate based on two columns and then apply function on one column vs the rest

Tags: python, python-polars

Hello I have below demonstrated DataFrame and attempting to generate an aggregated result based on `unique_id` and `cutoff` where there is a calculation of a metric (such as MSE) between `y` and the rest of columns, except group by ones and `ds`.

```
shape: (5, 10)
┌───────────┬─────┬────────┬───────┬───┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ unique_id ┆ ds  ┆ cutoff ┆ y     ┆ … ┆ CrostonClass ┆ SeasonalNaiv ┆ HistoricAver ┆ DynamicOptim │
│ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆   ┆ ic           ┆ e            ┆ age          ┆ izedTheta    │
│ str       ┆ i64 ┆ i64    ┆ f32   ┆   ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│           ┆     ┆        ┆       ┆   ┆ f32          ┆ f32          ┆ f32          ┆ f32          │
╞═══════════╪═════╪════════╪═══════╪═══╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ H1        ┆ 701 ┆ 700    ┆ 619.0 ┆ … ┆ 742.668762   ┆ 691.0        ┆ 661.674988   ┆ 612.767517   │
│ H1        ┆ 702 ┆ 700    ┆ 565.0 ┆ … ┆ 742.668762   ┆ 618.0        ┆ 661.674988   ┆ 536.846252   │
│ H1        ┆ 703 ┆ 700    ┆ 532.0 ┆ … ┆ 742.668762   ┆ 563.0        ┆ 661.674988   ┆ 497.82428    │
│ H1        ┆ 704 ┆ 700    ┆ 495.0 ┆ … ┆ 742.668762   ┆ 529.0        ┆ 661.674988   ┆ 464.723236   │
│ H1        ┆ 705 ┆ 700    ┆ 481.0 ┆ … ┆ 742.668762   ┆ 504.0        ┆ 661.674988   ┆ 440.972351   │
└───────────┴─────┴────────┴───────┴───┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

I was able to generate desired result with iteration, however, do not know how to concat all the DataFrames.

```py
from datasetsforecast.losses import mse, mae, rmse


def evaluate_cross_validation(df, metric):
    models = df.drop(columns=['ds', 'cutoff', 'y', 'unique_id']).columns
    evals = []

    for model in models:
      eval_ = (
          df
          .groupby(['unique_id', 'cutoff'])
          .agg(
              pl.apply(
                  exprs=['y', model],
                  function=lambda args: metric(args[0], args[1]),
              )
          )
          .rename({'y': model})
          .sort(by=['unique_id', 'cutoff'])
      )
      evals.append(eval_)
    
    uid_cutoff = evals[0].select(['unique_id'])
    eval_dfs = pl.concat([df.drop(['unique_id', 'cutoff']) for df in evals], how='horizontal')
    evals = pl.concat([uid_cutoff, eval_dfs], how='horizontal')
    evals = evals.groupby(['unique_id']).mean() # Averages the error metrics for all cutoffs for every combination of model and unique_id
    best_model = [min(row, key=row.get) for row in evals.drop('unique_id').rows(named=True)]
    evals = evals.with_columns(pl.lit(best_model).alias('best_model')).sort(by=['unique_id'])
    return evals
```

Expected output:

```
shape: (5, 8)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────┐
│ unique_id ┆ AutoARIMA ┆ HoltWinte ┆ CrostonCla ┆ SeasonalNa ┆ HistoricAv ┆ DynamicOpt ┆ best_mod │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ rs        ┆ ssic       ┆ ive        ┆ erage      ┆ imizedThet ┆ el       │
│ str       ┆ f64       ┆ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ a          ┆ ---      │
│           ┆           ┆ f64       ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ ---        ┆ str      │
│           ┆           ┆           ┆            ┆            ┆            ┆ f64        ┆          │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ H1        ┆ 1979.3021 ┆ 44888.019 ┆ 28038.7363 ┆ 1422.66668 ┆ 20927.6640 ┆ 1296.33398 ┆ DynamicO │
│           ┆ 85        ┆ 531       ┆ 28         ┆ 7          ┆ 62         ┆ 4          ┆ ptimized │
│           ┆           ┆           ┆            ┆            ┆            ┆            ┆ Theta    │
│ H10       ┆ 458.89271 ┆ 2812.9166 ┆ 1483.48413 ┆ 96.895832  ┆ 1980.36749 ┆ 379.621124 ┆ Seasonal │
│           ┆ 5         ┆ 26        ┆ 1          ┆            ┆ 3          ┆            ┆ Naive    │
│ H100      ┆ 8629.9482 ┆ 121625.37 ┆ 91945.1406 ┆ 12019.0    ┆ 78491.1914 ┆ 21699.6479 ┆ AutoARIM │
│           ┆ 42        ┆ 5         ┆ 25         ┆            ┆ 06         ┆ 49         ┆ A        │
│ H101      ┆ 6818.3486 ┆ 28453.395 ┆ 16183.6347 ┆ 10944.4580 ┆ 18208.4042 ┆ 63698.0732 ┆ AutoARIM │
│           ┆ 33        ┆ 508       ┆ 66         ┆ 08         ┆ 97         ┆ 42         ┆ A        │
│ H102      ┆ 65489.965 ┆ 232924.85 ┆ 132655.300 ┆ 12699.8959 ┆ 309110.468 ┆ 31393.5214 ┆ Seasonal │
│           ┆ 82        ┆ 1562      ┆ 781        ┆ 96         ┆ 75         ┆ 84         ┆ Naive    │
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you can use pl.concat to concatenate dataframes

Comment: @Luca I am getting the following error: `ShapeError: unable to vstack, column names don't match: "AutoARIMA" and "HoltWinters"`

Comment: @AkmalSoliev If the column names differ you can try a diagonal concat e.g. `how="diagonal"`

Comment: @jqurious when looking over documentation I believe that `how="align"` is the solution, however, it is not available on google Colab's version :(

Comment: Yes, you need `>= 0.17.14` for that feature. It combines all the frames using outer joins: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/functions/eager.py#L133-L157 which you can do manually if required.

Comment: I've achieved the goal by creating one dataframe with group by columns and then second list with the rest of dataframes excluding group by, then concat all of them together, seems to be the only way I found out so far sadly

Comment: If you could add a runnable example and the expected output it would help people answer. e.g. the code for `metric()` - it's difficult to tell what the issue is with just the current information.

Comment: @AkmalSoliev as mentioned by @jqurious, if you give a runnable working example then we can help you better. For Colab: you can upgrade to the latest version of Polars with `!pip install polars --upgrade`

Comment: @Luca seems that package that I'm using was caping polars version, not collar... Totally had tunnel vision there.

Comment: @jqurious will update the question with more info

Comment: Can you not apply all the models at once in a single groupby? `df.groupby().agg(pl.apply().alias(model) for model in models)`

Comment: @jqurious did apply that little change, does remove some bloat, but wondering if there is a more direct way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Hm, ok. But does that not mean you can remove all the concat code? I'll add it as an answer showing what I mean as it's too large for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example:

```
evaluate_cross_validation(df, mse)
```

```
shape: (1, 6)
┌───────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ unique_id ┆ CrostonClassic ┆ SeasonalNaive ┆ HistoricAverage ┆ DynamicOptimizedTheta ┆ best_model            │
│ ---       ┆ ---            ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   │
│ str       ┆ f64            ┆ f64           ┆ f64             ┆ f64                   ┆ str                   │
╞═══════════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ H1        ┆ 44210.367188   ┆ 2127.800049   ┆ 17681.363281    ┆ 903.670532            ┆ DynamicOptimizedTheta │
└───────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Is that not the same as running `.apply()` on all the models at once:

```
metric = mse

models = df.drop(columns=['ds', 'cutoff', 'y', 'unique_id']).columns

(
   df
   .groupby('unique_id', 'cutoff')
   .agg(
      pl.apply(
         exprs=['y', model],
         function=lambda args: metric(args[0], args[1]),
      ).alias(model)
      for model in models
   )
   .groupby('unique_id')
   .agg(
      pl.mean(models)
   )
   .with_columns(
      best_model = pl.min(models)
   )
)
```

```
shape: (1, 7)
┌───────────┬────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────┬────────────┐
│ unique_id ┆ cutoff ┆ CrostonClassic ┆ SeasonalNaive ┆ HistoricAverage ┆ DynamicOptimizedTheta ┆ best_model │
│ ---       ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---                   ┆ ---        │
│ str       ┆ i64    ┆ f64            ┆ f64           ┆ f64             ┆ f64                   ┆ f64        │
╞═══════════╪════════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪════════════╡
│ H1        ┆ 700    ┆ 44210.367188   ┆ 2127.800049   ┆ 17681.363281    ┆ 903.670532            ┆ 903.670532 │
└───────────┴────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

(Although you need the column/model name for `best_model` instead of the actual value.)

**Update:** To get the min name instead of the value. (perhaps there is a simpler way?)

```
.with_columns(best_model = 
   pl.concat_list(pl.col(models) == pl.min(models))
     .list.eval(pl.element().arg_true())
     .list.first()
     .map_dict(
        dict(enumerate(models))
     )
)
```

```
shape: (1, 6)
┌───────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ unique_id ┆ CrostonClassic ┆ SeasonalNaive ┆ HistoricAverage ┆ DynamicOptimizedTheta ┆ best_model            │
│ ---       ┆ ---            ┆ ---           ┆ ---             ┆ ---                   ┆ ---                   │
│ str       ┆ f32            ┆ f32           ┆ f32             ┆ f32                   ┆ str                   │
╞═══════════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ H1        ┆ 44210.367188   ┆ 2127.800049   ┆ 17681.363281    ┆ 903.670532            ┆ DynamicOptimizedTheta │
└───────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Very creative approach, thanks!